# mouseLeave event never triggered

Tags: html, hover, mouseleave

I'm trying to develop an overwolf app and am having issues receiving mouseLeave events.

**Overwolf App:**

```
<div id="menu" onMouseDown="dragMove();">
  <div id="close" onclick="closeWindow();"></div>
</div>

<iframe src="URL_to_Webpage"></iframe>

<div id="scale" onmousedown="dragResize('BottomLeft');"></div>
<div id="sliderBg">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

The menu, close, scale and slider elements are overlayed ("position: absolute; left:...") over the iframe and work as window control elements (scaling, closing,...)

**Webpage (iframe content):**

```
$('html').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

I always get the hover class applied to my iframe as expected. CSS :hover selectors get applied as well.

The mouseLeave event though is only triggered, when leaving the iframe without "touching" the overlayed window control elements.
So if I touch those elements on my way out with my mouse, the "hover" class isn't removed (event simply not triggered) and all things applied with a css ":hover" selector aren't removed either.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try add 'id' name on the iframe and imstead of directly using html. 
I would like to see how it works to fully picture what you want to do. 
Could you please paste your code at http://jsbin.com and let me know the link?

Comment: The webpage isn't part of the app, so due to cross domain restrictions the app can't access the iframes content and vice versa. So an id on the iframe won't do much.
The version in jsbin works. So i'm left to guess that it's an issue with overwolf -.- http://jsbin.com/muzigotunu/1/